# access object array in php from json decode

Tags: php

I have this response from `json_decode()`

```
// Decode JSON into PHP array
$response_data = json_decode($curl_data, true);

$user_data = $response_data;
var_dump($user_data);
```

Response :

```
array(3) { ["Items"]=> array(1) { [0]=> array(3) { ["date"]=> string(9) "4/12/2022" ["ongoing"]=> string(1) "1" ["id"]=> string(1) "1" } } ["Count"]=> int(1) ["ScannedCount"]=> int(1) }
```

now I just wanted to get the ongoing part so I did it like this

```
if(!empty($user_data))
{
  foreach($user_data as $user)
  {
    var_dump($user[0]->ongoing);
  }
}
```

but it gives me an error

[image]

`$user_data` has the response above. Why is it giving me an error like that

now I have a different error when I tried this

```
// Decode JSON into PHP array
$response_data = json_decode($curl_data, true);

// Print all data if needed
// print_r($response_data);
// die();

// All user data exists in 'data' object
$user_data = $response_data;

if(!empty($user_data))
{
  foreach($user_data as $user)
  {
    var_dump($user[0]['ongoing']);
  }
}
```

[image]

Comment: `$user_data` is an array, not an object. You must have told [json_decode](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php) to create an associated array.

Comment: In your loop your handle your item as object. `var_dump($user[0]->ongoing);` but you pass to the decode function the second parameter true. Then you have access like that: `$user[0]['ongoing']`

Comment: Look carefully at what your `var_dump` is telling you. Don't just glance at the bit you're interested in, follow it through from the outside in, looking at how the arrays nest inside each other. Think of it like a maze, where you have to describe every turn to get from where you are to where you want to go; you can't just skip passed turnings.

Comment: As IMSoP said, look very very carefully at your result. `$user_data` has 3 properties: Items, Count, and ScannedCount. Items is an array of arrays. When you iterate through user_data, the first time is fine because it's accessing Items, which contains an array with a single value, which has the key `ongoing`. But the next time through, it's Count, then it's ScannedCount

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your loop your handle your item as object. var_dump($user[0]->ongoing); but you pass to the decode function the second parameter true. Then you return an array. Afterwards you have access like that: `$user[0]['ongoing']` or you pass to the loop directly the items. See second example. Thank @IMSoP for the right hint!

### Update

The problem is that you have item, count and ScannedCount as key. But only item has the property `ongoing`. You need a condition to check if the key `ongoing`exists. Then it works.

**version 1 (with key check)**

```php
$str = '{"Items":[{"date":"4/12/2022","ongoing":"1","id":"1"}],"Count":1,"ScannedCount":1}';
$user_data = json_decode($str, true);

if (! empty($user_data)) {
    foreach($user_data as $key => $value) {
        if ($key === 'Items') {
           print_r($value[0]['ongoing']);   
        }
        
    }   
}
```

**Version 2 (pass items directly to loop)**

```php
$str = '{"Items":[{"date":"4/12/2022","ongoing":"1","id":"1"}],"Count":1,"ScannedCount":1}';
$user_data = json_decode($str, true);

if (! empty($user_data)) {
    foreach ($user_data['items'] as $value) {
       print_r($value[0]['ongoing']);           
    }   
}
```

Comment: sorry but already did something like that . Forgot to add the code I am very sorry

Comment: @JustANoob No problem. I update my answer. ;-)

Comment: Just updated my question because i have tried that also

Comment: @JustANoob Can you share the json String please!?

Comment: `var_dump($user);` `array(1) { [0]=> array(3) { ["date"]=> string(9) "4/12/2022" ["ongoing"]=> string(1) "1" ["id"]=> string(1) "1" } } int(1) int(1)` . That's the string

Comment: while `var_dump($user[0]['ongoing']);` `string(1) "1"` is this

Comment: @JustANoob the is a var dump. make `print_r($curl_data));`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/243829/discussion-between-maik-lowrey-and-justanoob).

Comment: @JustANoob I update my answer!

Comment: I totally understand it now. I should've checked for the key. Thank you so much for making an explanation sir. Marked your answer as correct. Thank you.

Comment: If you're only looking for one key, there's no need for a loop - `foreach($user_data as $key => $value) { if ($key === 'Items') { ... } }` can be simplified to `$value = $user_data['items'];`

Comment: @IMSoP Your are so right! I will change it... Thanks